# "Application windows are expected..." error when loading storyboard for Ipad

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, storyboard

I'm loading different storyboards for Iphone and Ipad and the Iphone's storyboards load good but when I start the Ipad Simulator I got the "Application windows are expected..." error.

this is the code in AppDelegate:

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (UIStoryboard *)grabStoryboard {

    UIStoryboard *storyboard;

    // detect the height of our screen
    int height = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;

    if (height == 480) {
        storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard_Iphone3" bundle:nil];
        // NSLog(@"Device has a 3.5inch Display.");
    }

    if (height >= 1024 && height <= 2048 ) {
        storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard_Ipad" bundle:nil];
        NSLog(@"Device has a 4inch Display.");
    }

    else {
        storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard_Iphone4Up" bundle:nil];
        // NSLog(@"Device has a 4inch Display.");
    }

    return storyboard;
}


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [self grabStoryboard];

    // show the storyboard
    self.window.rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

In the console I see the NSLog message but the storyboard doesn't load and the "Application windows..." error appears.

I'm using some Scroll Views and some elements but i thinkg those are not the problem because there is an option for them "Adjust Scroll View Insets".

I uploaded some screen shots to show more about my project. Thanks for your time.

[image] 
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. When you copy all stuff from the Iphone storyboard to the Ipad one the Initial View Controller checkbox is unchecked. Just check it and all will be good (: